# Is there any way that a function can accept either of two similar types as an argument?

Tags: function, go, struct

For instance let's say I have a function called `calc` and it takes in a `Foo` as an argument. But `Bar` is similar enough to `Foo` that it could also be used in the `calc` function -- `Foo` and `Bar` share the 3 or 4 fields that I need to do `calc` but `Bar` has a few other fields.

Is there any way to write a function so that a `Foo` or a `Bar` can be passed in?

In a language like [C# I'd use an interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/interface-properties) as the argument to `calc` so that any thing that satisfies the contract can be used in the function. What's the equivalent to that in Go?

Comment: You can still use an interface, but then you have to define getter/setter methods for both types.

Comment: meaning I'd have to supply functions like `GetQuarter` and `GetYear` in `Foo` and `Bar` so that `calc` can perform its calculations?

Comment: I'm sure you must be aware that Go does not currently have generics, so there is no possibility of a direct equivalent. You can create behavior based interfaces, or you can do runtime checks.

Comment: @JimB yep I think you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to this:

1. Use an interface and add getters for the fields you need to access in `calc`
2. Wait for Generics to be added to Go:

> We will use the feedback we gather from the Go community to decide how
> to move forward. If the draft design is well received and doesn’t need
> significant changes, the next step would be a formal language change
> proposal. To set expectations, if everybody is completely happy with
> the design draft and it does not require any further adjustments, **the
> earliest that generics could be added to Go would be the Go 1.17
> release, scheduled for August 2021**. In reality, of course, there may
> be unforeseen problems, so this is an optimistic timeline; we can’t
> make any definite prediction.

https://blog.golang.org/generics-next-step